# Simplenews: How send mail(newsletter) with images

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How can in get images to be displayed in the send simple news mails...
i search the web but no success.
I set up mime mail system etc, tried relative and direct paths but no success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a good reference and now all is working well!
http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2012/04/04/drupal-7-create-newsletter-by-simplenews-2/